# Django how to make a form

Tags: python, django, forms

I try to make an user registration form, how do make a form to this code:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

class Profile(models.Model):
    STUDENT = 1
    TEACHER = 2
    SUPERVISOR = 3
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
       (STUDENT, 'Student'),
       (TEACHER, 'Teacher'),
       (SUPERVISOR, 'Supervisor'),
    )
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    role = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ for Python 2
        return self.user.username

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_or_update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

Create this form I don't know how to made this

Comment: what do you mean? the html code? the form.py file?

Comment: forms.py file i need to make

Comment: Your question is too vague. What do you want to show in the form? What have you tried? Have you read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/)? What exactly is the issue you're facing?

Comment: I read documentation but can't understand

Comment: Although the documentation may be too wide, the tutorials are very well made. You can learn a lot from them

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you only have the model right?

Well, you should take a luck to this tutorials, are very good and should adapt to your needs

[Tuto 1](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/18/how-to-create-user-sign-up-view.html)

[Tuto 2](https://dev.to/coderasha/create-advanced-user-sign-up-view-in-django-step-by-step-k9m)